# While loop won't continue

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

```
int Day = 20;
while (Day >= 1)
{
   cout << Day << " ";
   userNum = Day / 2;
   cin >> Day;
}
```

I don't get why the loop doesn't work. I want the output to be `20 10 5 2 1`

Any help and if possible with explanation.

Comment: What the heck is this code supposed to mean? `Day` is equal to 20, so the loop won't even start as it's _not_ equal to one.

Comment: 20 != 1 ... maybe you meant `while (Day >= 1) ... and remove the semicolon after the loop head.

Comment: Sorry had an older version of the task , still doesn't work though

Comment: You're assigning the division of `Day` by `2` to a new variable, essentially keeping `Day` the same... And then why do you `cin >> Day` after that?

Comment: whats the purpose of `cin` here?

Comment: right.... Thanks Guys , I'm completely new to c++ I though I had to add it to the Day Variable again. Fixed it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what the purpose of `cin` is here, but if you want the output you requested in the question:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
 int Day = 20;
  while (Day >= 1)
  {
    cout << Day << " ";
    Day /= 2;
  }
}
```

You can see you stop whenever `Date` reaches 1 or is less than 1. And you divide it by 2 repeatedly. First, it becomes 20; then you divide it by 2 and it reaches 10; then you divide by two again and it reaches 5; then 5/2 is 2.5 but rounds to 2; and then 2/2 is 1, and finally exits the program.

[**Here**](http://cpp.sh/9bvtf) it is compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int Day = 20;
while (Day >= 1)
{
    cout << Day << " ";
    Day = Day / 2;      
}
```